# How to enforce a 1 to n relationship

Tags: sql, locking, integrity

I'm working on an online muiltiplayer board game & have a SQL server question.

Lets assume the game allows two players. When the game is created, the creator is added as the first user.

At that point, two users could try to join the game simultaneously. One of these users should be blocked.

My database schema is as follows:

```
tbGame - contains a list of all games. PrimaryKey is GameId
tbPlayers - contains a list of all registered users. PrimaryKey is PlayerId
tbPlayersInGame - contains a list of all players in each game. Foreign key 
                  relations to tbGame and tbPlayers.
```

I feel like I need two things:

1. A way to lock tbPlayersInGame based on the GameId. This would be used while adding a player to a game. From what I've read it sounds like a key-range lock (on GameId) would be suitable.
2. A way to enforce a 1-to-2 relationship so that attempts to add a 3rd player would fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple suggestions:

1) When you try to write to the tbPlayersInGame table first do a SELECT to make sure the game isn't full, then INSERT INTO the table.  Wrap this SELECT and the INSERT INTO in a transaction with the transaction isolation level set to serializable.

2) Don't have a separate tbPlayersInGame table, instead have 2 fields in tbGame: Player1Id, Player2Id

Comment: I ended up taking this approach. The query was something like: 

'SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
 BEGIN TRANSACTION 
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PlayersInGame WHERE GameId = @GameId < SELECT MaxPlayers FROM Game WHERE GameId = @GameId)
 BEGIN
 INSERT INTO PlayersInGame ... 
COMMIT TRAN
RETURN 0
END

ROLLBACK TRAN
RETURN -1'

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a 1-to-n relationship, you could set up your table to have to columns - probably labelled `host_player` and `visitor_player`, or the necessary equivalent (like in chess - `black` and `white`).  This has the advantage of keeping funny things to a minimum, and showing the natural state of the relationship.

This of course only works if there is supposed to be a *permanently limited* number of players - for most instances of boardgames, this will likely work fine....

If you are attempting to make a game where the upper limit is mutable (for whatever reason), you can 'detect' free slots available with the following statement:

```
INSERT INTO game_players (game_id, player_id) 
SELECT VALUES (:GAME_ID, :PLAYER_ID)
WHERE :MAX_PLAYER_COUNT > (SELECT COUNT(*)
                           FROM game_players
                           WHERE game_id = :GAME_ID)
```

If you get back an error-code of 100 ('No rows selected/updated), the player list is full.  You may need to add other conditions (to prevent players from joining twice), but the concept should still work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I should have been more clear, the game can have a varying number of players from 2-8. Given that I was avoiding adding the players to the Game table. 

I don't think you can add a where clause to an insert statement in SQL Server, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Ack, you're right, you can't just add a `WHERE` clause - I meant to put it as part of a `SELECT`... editing.